# OutOfMemory exception in converting ByteArray to String?

Tags: java, android, string, arrays, out-of-memory

I use the following code for converting my ByteArray to String:

```
String sReturn = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

But I get the following exception when ByteArray is large enough.

Is there any other way to convert ByteArray to String without Out of memory exception?

```
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/dalvikvm(1617): Out of memory: Heap Size=30663KB, Allocated=22087KB, Bitmap Size=936KB, Limit=32768KB
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/dalvikvm(1617): Extra info: Footprint=30663KB, Allowed Footprint=30663KB, Trimmed=616KB
06-17 12:27:37.594: W/dalvikvm(1617): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d648)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-19
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=30663KB, Allocated=22087KB, Bitmap Size=936KB)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:422)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:276)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities.decompress(Utilities.java:389)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.utils.WebserviceResponse.getClearedResponse(WebserviceResponse.java:18)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.businessLayer.BoWebService.getDataForUpdate(BoWebService.java:216)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.threadGetDataForFullUpdate(ActToolDataExchange.java:389)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange.access$9(ActToolDataExchange.java:380)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActToolDataExchange$35.run(ActToolDataExchange.java:639)
06-17 12:27:37.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities$4.run(Utilities.java:924)
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
public static String decompress(String zipText) throws IOException {
    byte[] compressed = Base64.decode(zipText);
    if (compressed.length > 4) {
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed, 4,
                        compressed.length - 4));

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int value = 0; value != -1;) {
            value = gzipInputStream.read();
            if (value != -1) {
                baos.write(value);
            }
        }
        gzipInputStream.close();
        baos.close();

        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        Log.i("toByteArray", String.valueOf(byteArray.length));

        String sReturn = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");

        return sReturn;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}



public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String password)
        throws Exception {

    byte[] encrypteddata = Base64.decode(encrypted);

    byte[] bytes = decrypt(encrypteddata, password);

    String result = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");

    return result;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted, String password)
        throws Exception {

    byte[] passwordKey = encodeDigest(password);
    try {
        aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: No such algorithm\r\n" + e
                        .toString());
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: No such padding PKCS5\r\n" + e
                        .toString());
    }
    secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

    try {
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: Invalid key\r\n" + e.toString());
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: Invalid algorithm\r\n" + e
                        .toString());
    }

    byte[] encryptedData;
    try {
        encryptedData = aesCipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: Illegal block size\r\n" + e
                        .toString());
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        throw new Exception(
                "Decryption Exception: Bad padding\r\n" + e
                        .toString());
    }
    return encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: What size would be the string ? If it's very big, are you sure you want to have it as one string ?

Comment: Do you know the size of ByteArray that causes the exception to be thrown? Would it be possible to check the size of ByteArray prior to conversion and if over this critical size, convert in smaller steps maybe?

Comment: The size of ByteArray is 3663125 Bytes

Comment: how can I convert in smaller steps?

Comment: @breceivemail - what are you going to do with that String later? Maybe you can return a stream instead.

Comment: at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities.decompress
If it's gzip decompression, you need to use GZIPInputStream instead, and yes, you need to use input streams and readers instead.

Comment: Is it possible to merge decrypt and decompress methods?

Comment: It seems that you need to show me your decrypt function code

Comment: I wouldn't have either the 3.5M byte array *or* the 3.5M string, let alone try to have them both at the same time as you are doing. I would find a way to process the input as it comes in. Less latency, less memory.

Comment: Ok, great, you need to use [Cipher Streams](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch13_06.htm). And [Base64InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html)

Comment: Does it support .Net? My encrypted string is created in .Net

Comment: it's just an example. check it out - http://pastebin.com/J5r5HQqv
sure, AES is open algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet will help you.Try to read in chunks

```
             StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();  

             Log.v("abc","length : " + byteArray.length);  

             while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {    
                 byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);    
                 // byteRead = in.read(dataBytes);    
                 //totalBytesRead += byteRead;    
                 sb.append((char)byteRead);  
             }    

              String s=sb.toString();
```

Comment: Except that it's not wise to handle a 3MB string.

Comment: My string is Unicode. Is it true ti use `sb.append((char)byteRead);`?

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into like a 1000 char strings at a time. 3663125 bytes is a lot of memory, especially for android.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
byte[] set = new byte[1000];
for(int x = 0, index = 0; x < byteArray.length;x++, index++)
{
    set[index] = byteArray[x];
    if(index == 999)
    {
        strings.add(new String(set, "Unicode"));
        index = 0;
        if(byteArray.length - x < 1000) // shorten the set when there are less than 1000 bytes left
            set = new byte[byteArray.length - x];
   }
}

strings.add(new String(set, "Unicode"));

String stringArray[] = (String[])strings.toArray();
```

This will break it up for you, you can change the 1000 to be whatever you want if thats too small.

Comment: My string is Unicode. Is it true ti use `string = string + ((char)byteArray[x]);`?

Comment: @breceivemail see my edit, i changed it so the bytes will be converted using unicode.

Comment: In Unicode string we have some bad data conversion when byteArray is splited.

Comment: In Unicode: [1,2,3,4,5] -> orig string, [1,2]->string1, [3,4,5] -> string2, orig string <> string1 + string2

Comment: Where is the ByteArray coming from before its turned into a ByteArray? you could split it up before you turn it into a ByteArray.

Comment: It is a zipped string. It can not be splitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory  excessively - first you decompress base 64 and allocate buffer for this, then you  decompress it and write in chutnks to BAOS ( which is  alocating and reallocating chunks of memory )   and the you copy it again to string - no wonder it runs out of memory.

Try to rewrite this to streaming process ( there is srteaming base64 dcoding, as well as gzip decoder )